# creating dynamic sharepoint list field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, team-sites

I have a SP team site list that contains fields describing widgets, one of which is an ID field that corresponds to an ID in my document library. In my list, I'm looking to create a URL field "Go to documents" that will link to a search of my document library for the relevant ID field. My goal is to build a dynamic string of `"domain.sharepoint.com/.../.../...&?=" & list.ID` and set up a workflow or other mechanism to automatically populate it when a new record in my list is added. I can't seem to figure out how to make that happen. I've gotten as far as being able to create a variable in Designer, but can't seem to make it reference the contents of another field.

I'm by no means a sharepoint designer. My background is in databases so maybe I'm even approaching it completely wrong. Hopefully my description makes sense. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Edit with a more specific example:
Say my list is about various projects. Starting new project, I create an entry on the list and give it an ID. Moving forward, we have various documents that will be related to that project. We will upload those documents and give them the same ID as the project on the list. The goal is to have a link from the list to the document library filtered by the project ID.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the lookup field type. This field type will link to another list or library. The steps are as mentioned below.

- Under List Settings page click on create column.

[image]

- Then on next screen enter the name of the list and then make the selection as highlighted in the picture below.

[image]

- You will then be able to select the IDs of the document library from
  the drop-down while adding or editing the list item.
- Once the item is created you can see the column with the hyperlink to
  the referenced item from other list or library.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the response. This doesn't quite do what I'm looking for. It looks like we would have to go and update this field any time we add a new related item to the document library. 

Maybe my question wasn't clear. Say my list is about various projects. Starting new project, I create an entry on the list and give it an ID. Moving forward, we have various documents that will be related to that project. We will upload those documents and give them the same ID as the project on the list. The goal is to have a link from the list to the document library filtered by the project

Comment: @Shabz, Thank you for the clarification, I believe that this method above still holds good for your scenario and this is just one time exercise which need to be setup while defining the column(Metadata for document library). In your case you can define a lookup column with the name Project in your document library and refer to the title or ID column from the projects list. 

Hope this explanation is helpful.